# Weight Painting

Tags: rigging, armature

I'm using 2.8, and wondering if someone could point me in the right direction as to solving whatever causes this:
[image]

Comment: a bone must influence this part of your mesh, in Edit mode, select it, then go in the Properties panel > Data > Vertex Groups, and use the down arrow in the right of the vertex groups list and choose Remove From All Groups

Comment: Thanks for the assist, moonboots.  Worked perfectly.  Is there a place/location on Stackexchange to reflect this was a good/correct response?

Answer (score 0):

A bone is influencing this part of your mesh. Solution: In *Edit* mode, select it, then go in the *Properties* panel > *Data* > *Vertex Groups*, and use the down arrow in the right of the vertex groups list and choose *Remove From All Groups*.

[image]